# Regular expression to remove XML tags and their content

Tags: c#, .net, xml, vb.net, regex

I have the following string and I would like to remove `<bpt *>*</bpt>` and `<ept *>*</ept>` (notice the additional tag content inside them that also needs to be removed)  without using a XML parser (overhead too large for tiny strings).

```
The big <bpt i="1" x="1" type="bold"><b></bpt>black<ept i="1"></b></ept> <bpt i="2" x="2" type="ulined"><u></bpt>cat<ept i="2"></u></ept> sleeps.
```

Any regex in VB.NET or C# will do.

Comment: What do you mean by filter? Extract? Remove? Please clarify.

Comment: What is the reason for avoiding an XML parser?

Comment: Small strings need to be filtered, so XML Parser overhead is not acceptable.

Filter is remove in that case.

Comment: Can a <bpt> be nested inside of an <ept>?  Or vice-versa?  That complicates the problem if so.

Comment: If there's arbitrary nesting, there is no general solution involving regexes, and with limited nesting your regexes get really huge and really ugly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want to remove all the tags from the string, use this (C#):

```
try {
    yourstring = Regex.Replace(yourstring, "(<[be]pt[^>]+>.+?</[be]pt>)", "");
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

EDIT:

I decided to add on to my solution with a better option.  The previous option would not work if there were embedded tags.  This new solution should strip all <**pt*> tags, embedded or not.  In addition, this solution uses a back reference to the original [be] match so that the exact matching end tag is found.  This solution also creates a reusable Regex object for improved performance so that each iteration does not have to recompile the Regex:

```
bool FoundMatch = false;

try {
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"<([be])pt[^>]+>.+?</\1pt>");
    while(regex.IsMatch(yourstring) ) {
        yourstring = regex.Replace(yourstring, "");
    }
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

ADDITIONAL NOTES:

In the comments a user expressed worry that the '.' pattern matcher would be cpu intensive.  While this is true in the case of a standalone greedy '.', the use of the non-greedy character '?' causes the regex engine to only look ahead until it finds the first match of the next character in the pattern versus a greedy '.' which requires the engine to look ahead all the way to the end of the string.  I use [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) as a regex development tool, and it includes a debugger which lets you see the relative performance of different regex patterns.  It also auto comments your regexes if desired, so I decided to include those comments here to explain the regex used above:

```
    // <([be])pt[^>]+>.+?</\1pt>
// 
// Match the character "<" literally «<»
// Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «([be])»
//    Match a single character present in the list "be" «[be]»
// Match the characters "pt" literally «pt»
// Match any character that is not a ">" «[^>]+»
//    Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
// Match the character ">" literally «>»
// Match any single character that is not a line break character «.+?»
//    Between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «+?»
// Match the characters "</" literally «</»
// Match the same text as most recently matched by backreference number 1 «\1»
// Match the characters "pt>" literally «pt>»
```

Comment: Nice one, except the use of "." which is pretty cpu intensive, that matters if you process a big xml file. You could just replace it by "[^<>]", couldn't you ?

Comment: Sorry, for the subtag, you just can't. Better use "[^ø]" instead.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you want to drop the tag entirely?

```
(<bpt .*?>.*?</bpt>)|(<ept .*?>.*?</ept>)
```

The ? after the * makes it non-greedy, so it will try to match as few characters as possible.

One problem you'll have is nested tags. stuff would not see the second  because the first matched.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you say the overhead is too large?  Did you measure it?  Or are you guessing?

Using a regex instead of a proper parser is a shortcut that you may run afoul of when someone comes along with something like  <bpt foo="bar>">

Comment: Well, using a regex or some other crutch is the only thing you can do when you have non-wellformed XML. The markup in the question is not XML, it has intersecting hierarchies.

Answer (score 0):

Does the .NET regex engine support negative lookaheads? If yes, then you can use

```
(<([eb])pt[^>]+>((?!</\2pt>).)+</\2pt>)
```

Which makes *The big black cat sleeps.* out of the string above if you remove all matches. However keep in mind that it will not work if you have nested `bpt`/`ept` elements.
You might also want to add `\s` in some places to allow for extra whitespace in closing elements etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use a regex to remove XML elements, you'd better be sure that your input XML doesn't use elements from different namespaces, or contain CDATA sections whose content you don't want to modify.

The proper (i.e. both performant and correct) way to do this is with XSLT.  An XSLT transform that copies everything except a specific element to the output is a trivial extension of the identity transform.  Once the transform is compiled it will execute extremely quickly.  And it won't contain any hidden defects.

Answer (score 0):

is there any possible way to get a global solution of the regex.pattern for xml type of text? 
that way i"ll get rid of the replace function and shell use the regex. 
The trouble is to analyze the < > coming in order or not.. 
Also replacing reserved chars as ' & and so on.
here is the code
 'handling special chars functions 
  Friend Function ReplaceSpecChars(ByVal str As String) As String
    Dim arrLessThan As New Collection
    Dim arrGreaterThan As New Collection
    If Not IsDBNull(str) Then

```
  str = CStr(str)
  If Len(str) > 0 Then
    str = Replace(str, "&", "&amp;")
    str = Replace(str, "'", "&apos;")
    str = Replace(str, """", "&quot;")
    arrLessThan = FindLocationOfChar("<", str)
    arrGreaterThan = FindLocationOfChar(">", str)
    str = ChangeGreaterLess(arrLessThan, arrGreaterThan, str)
    str = Replace(str, Chr(13), "chr(13)")
    str = Replace(str, Chr(10), "chr(10)")
  End If
  Return str
Else
  Return ""
End If
```

End Function
  Friend Function ChangeGreaterLess(ByVal lh As Collection, ByVal gr As Collection, ByVal str As String) As String
      For i As Integer = 0 To lh.Count
           If CInt(lh.Item(i)) > CInt(gr.Item(i)) Then
                str = Replace(str, "<", "<")          /////////problems////
           End If

```
  Next


    str = Replace(str, ">", "&gt;")
```

End Function
  Friend Function FindLocationOfChar(ByVal chr As Char, ByVal str As String) As Collection
        Dim arr As New Collection
        For i As Integer = 1 To str.Length() - 1
            If str.ToCharArray(i, 1) = chr Then
                arr.Add(i)
            End If
        Next
        Return arr
  End Function

got trouble at problem mark

that's a standart xml with different tags i want to analyse..

Answer (score 0):

Have you measured this?  I *have* run into performance issues using .NET's regex engine, but by contrast have parsed xml files of around 40GB *without* issue using the Xml parser (you will need to use XmlReader for larger strings, however).

Please post a an actual code sample and mention your performance requirements: I doubt the `Regex` class is the best solution here if performance matters.