# Removing XML-tag via regex

Tags: xml, regex, tags

Greetings, 
I've read some threads about this topic, but actually I was unable to find or to think of a adequate solution (see for example: [Regular expression to remove XML tags and their content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121656/regular-expression-to-remove-xml-tags-and-their-content)).

I have an xml tag like that:

```
<bla_tag size="100"
         diameter="50"
         ratio="0.2"
         path="/user/home/something.pdf">
</bla_tag>
```

Aim: Having a regular expression that removes everything in between `<bla_tag ...>` .

Problem: the values like size, etc. change in each of the bla_tags (about 1000 bla-tags in the file).

Failed attempt: I tried it with: `<bla_tag .*?>`  (the ? to make it less greedy...).
Result of failure: Only `<bla_tag` has been marked, but not the content within the entire bracket!

What am I doing wrong - or is it actually possible to solve this problem based on regex (I read somewhere that it would not be possible due to xml property to be an type-2 language, can you confirm that?)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: On what particular programming/scripting language will you apply this?

Comment: Your regex looks ok. How do you use it?

Comment: Jens, I tried typing in this regex into the search field of kate (editor for linux) - and it does not work, for any reasons. I also tried 'Scream Editor' but it also was marked by failure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to read [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Seriously.

Use an xml parser. (They're not hard to use, honestly). They generally come in one of two flavours - SAX, and DOM, and you're probably going to prefer SAX.

My favorite parser is expat, but they all each have their little subtleties so it's not always a one-size-fits-all.

Comment: Thanks a lot and apologies for the late response. Specially the Automata/Regex part included in the mentioned link helped me. Due to my theoretical computer science lessons now I can also understand why a xml parser is preferable.