# What is a clean way to parse multiple sections of a string in C#?

Tags: c#, string, asp.net-mvc-3, encoding, mathml

I have a string that may contain XML and normal string.  I need to parse out the `<math....</math>` for all instances in a string.  How can I parse out multiple sections of this (from `<math>` to `</math>`) from this string?

```
Here is some content <math
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">  
<mi>a</mi><mo>&#x2260;</mo><mn>0</mn> </math>, that is mixed in with
this other content <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">  
<mi>a</mi><msup><mi>x</mi><mn>2</mn></msup>   <mo>+</mo>
<mi>b</mi><mi>x</mi>   <mo>+</mo> <mi>c</mi> <mo>=</mo> <mn>0</mn>
</math> we want to be able to seperate this string
```

**Background**:
I tried to make this question generic.  The specifics of what I'm trying to do is for MVC3 encoding versus Raw.  It will encode everything by default.  I don't want it to encode MathML, but do want it to encode everything else.  So parts of it I want to render out as Html.Raw (the MathML part) and the rest I want to render as normally encoded strings.

Comment: Are you able to change the format of this data?  It's often difficult to parse a somewhat inconsistent data format in a "clean" way.

Comment: Yes, the input of this data is a string.  I suppose I can convert to whatever I need to better help parse it.

Comment: Well, I mean the format of the string.  A string is fine, but mixing XML with non-xml is a bad idea in most cases (as you have discovered).  If it were compliant XML then you could simply use .NET's XML parsers.

Comment: @EdS. agreed but it does make me wonder how MarkDown does it.

Comment: The data can be mixed.  It's just the way I receive it, so can't change the source format of the file.

Comment: Markdown is consistent.  It is a well defined format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no regular expression boffin, but this is what I tried and I got back the correct result.  Please use it as a base and modify it where necessary.

I got it from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121656/regular-expression-to-remove-xml-tags-and-their-content) on Stackoverflow.

```
string yourstring = "<math xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML\">   <mi>a</mi><mo>&#x2260;</mo><mn>0</mn> </math>, that is mixed in with this other content <math xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML\">   <mi>a</mi><msup><mi>x</mi><mn>2</mn></msup>   <mo>+</mo> <mi>b</mi><mi>x</mi>   <mo>+</mo> <mi>c</mi> <mo>=</mo> <mn>0</mn> </math>";

try
{
     yourstring = Regex.Replace(yourstring, "(<math[^>]+>.+?</math>)", "");
}
catch (ArgumentException ex)
{
     // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

The resulting string is:

```
, that is mixed in with this other content
```

Comment: that could work.  Let me play with that and see if I can get it going.

Answer (score 1):

If you can generally expect the XML to be well-formatted, or at least consistently formatted, you should be able to use [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to strip out the XML.

You can experiment with [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) to craft your expression.

If you want to then parse the XML you strip out, that's a job for the .NET XMLParser.